# ZipArchive in PHP does not unzip file

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

Here is the code I use

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
     $res = $zip->open('file.zip');
     if ($res === TRUE) {
         $zip->extractTo('myextractdir/');
         $zip->close();
         echo 'Extracted';
     } else {
         echo 'failed';
     }
?>
```

It just outputs Extracted, but no files show up. The file is a zip file..

Comment: Please check file permissions. Is the directory read-only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please check file permissions. Is the directory read-only?

If the directory is read-only, please set file permissions in either Windows or Linux.